# 'org.h2.server.web.WebServlet' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Servlet,jakarta.servlet.Servlet'

Tags: java, servlets, h2, jakarta-migration

I'm using **jakarta.jakartaee-api 9.1.0** and **H2 2.1.212**.

I get this error when I try to add **H2 Console Servlet** to web.xml file:

> 'org.h2.server.web.WebServlet' is not assignable to
> 'javax.servlet.Servlet,jakarta.servlet.Servlet'

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="5.0"
         xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd">
    <data-source>
        <name>java:global/dataSource</name>
        <class-name>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</class-name>
        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=LEGACY</url>
    </data-source>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/h2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: See also [_Using the H2 Console Servlet_](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#usingH2ConsoleServlet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `jakarta.*` packages

The package namespace for Jakarta 9 and 9.1 is `jakarta.*`. This [changed from the old `javax.*` naming](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/post/jakarta-ee-9-is-released) during the transition of Oracle handing over Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation where it became Jakarta EE.

I poked around the H2 codebase on GitHub, and found [`JakartaWebServlet`](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/web/JakartaWebServlet.java). This seems to be the same Servlet but using the `jakarta.*` packages. You may be able to switch from:

```
<servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
```

… to:

```
<servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet</servlet-class>
```

See the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#usingH2ConsoleServlet).

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you and also @trashgod for your help. As a comment I found it in H2 official document: *If your application is already Servlet 5-compatible, use the servlet class org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet instead.* [link](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#usingH2ConsoleServlet)